# "Error 8525:Eithe enlist this session in a new transaction or the null transaction" in a distributed transaction with many records transfer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I have a linked server from SQL2008 to SQL2kSp3.

I want to Insert,Update,Delete records in SQL2008 according to inserted,updated,deleted records in SQL2kSp3.

All of my statements are between Distributed transaction and commit.

I don't have any problem when I want to do these operation in small data. I tested it on 3 records and operation will do in about 20 seconds. But when I'm testing it in many recods about 1000 records it takes about 20 minutes and  I recieve this error message:

```
Distributed transaction completed. Eithe enlist this session in a new transaction or the null transaction[SQLSTATE 42000][Error 8525] The step failed
```

I executed `Instcat.sql` on SQL2k and restarted my sqlserver but I have the same problem.

It's better to say the first I had sql2k without Service pack and then I installed Sql2kSp3 to upgrade it but when I execute

`select @@version` I don't see Spk3 in the version of sql.

operating systems:

Sql2008 installed on Windowsxp SP2

Sql2k installed on windows 2003 service pack2

Bandwidth is about:256Kbps

Please hepl me.